# Android Media recorder

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

How can i record only in app audio,using Media recorder.
currently we are doing this one

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);                                     
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

This is recording background voice also, we want to directly record sound from the app it self.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the audio source to be the mic.  SO of course it will pick up background noises.

The best fit for what you want seems to be REMOTE_SUBMIX.  But that only exists as of Android v19.  Previosu to that it doesn't look like MediaRecorder has that capability.